# write to file specified by the user

Tags: c

readFromFile() function is used at the start of the program.

When the user writes a name of a file the program should read data from that file if the file exists, if the file with that name does not exist it should keep the name entered by the user and before closing the program write it to that file with the writeToFile() function.

The issue is in fp=fopen(a,"w"); the writeTofile() function does not recognize a, so it does not know what name the user entered at the begining of the program. My thinking is that since I have FILE *fp in both it should recognize that "a". But it does not I cannot figure out how to do it.

to summ it up. writeTofile() function needs to know what filename user wrote in readFromFile().

```
void readFromFile(Car reg[], int *pNrOfCars){
   
    FILE *fp;
    char a[100];
    printf("filename: ");
    fscanf(stdin,"%s",a);
    strcat(a,".txt");
    fp=fopen(a,"r");

    if(fp!=NULL){
        char model[WORDLENGTH];
        int year,milage;  
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s %d %d",model,&year,&milage)==3){
        reg[*pNrOfCars]=createCar(model,year,milage); 
        (*pNrOfCars)++;  
        }
      fclose(fp); 
    }     
}
```

```
void writeToFile(Car reg[], int nrOfCars){

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(a,"w");
    if(fp!=NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCars; i++){
        fprintf(fp,"%s %d %d\n", reg[i].model, reg[i].year, reg[i].milage);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should get the filename *outside* the `readFromFile` function, and pass it as an argument to both the `readFromFile` and `writeToFile` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `a` is inside the `readFromFile()` function, and thus not visible from the outside.

One "solution" is to make it global, i.e. define it outside all functions:

```
char a[100];

void readFromFile(Car reg[], int *pNrOfCars){
  /* ... */
}
```

then it would be visible from inside any function, but global variables are generally not a good idea since they are messy and make it harder to understand a program.

It's better to pass the filename to the function, by adding an argument:

```
void readFromFile(Car reg[], int *pNrOfCars, const char *filename) {
  /* ... use filename instead of a ... */
}
```

then move the code that gets the filename to the `main()` function, since reading the name is something that is not specific to reading it should not be done inside the file:

```
int main(void)
{
   char fname[100];
   printf("filename: ");
   fscanf(stdin,"%s", fname);
   strcat(fname, ".txt");  
   
   readFromFile(..., fname);
   /* ... process data ... */
   writeToFile(..., fname);

   return 0;
}
```

I skipped some details, marked by "...".

Comment: thank you i will try this solution and the one before. But should it not be fname instead of a in fscanf and strcat?

Comment: @Dlrs Yes, totally. I blame copy-paste. Thanks.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! 7 hours already on this problem. One question. I'm not allowed to have global variables, as you mentioned they are no good. but if I pass const char as argumenet it is not considered as global varaible right?since it is not declared outside the main.  I have not used const before so that is why.

Comment: @Dlrs No, the filename is now a local variable in the `main()` function, and then passed down into the other functions as needed. It's not a global.

Comment: Understood. I just run into an issue. when I create a file and restart the program to read from that file it does not read from it. If I create a file named cars and restart the program to read from cars the only thing that comes up is Filename, and when i type cars the program stops. EDIT: nvm, I just tried it on my smaller program and it worked so must be something wrong with my original program.

Answer (score 2):

Do this part in a separate function:

```
    char a[100];
    printf("filename: ");
    fscanf(stdin,"%s",a);
    strcat(a,".txt");
```

And then pass `a` to both function `readFromFile` and function `writeToFile`.